# UIDatePicker.time problem if I have to enter 24.00

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently I use form la to insert a start time and an end time and calculate the difference in hours and minutes.

Everything works, the problem is that with the datePicker.time I can only select until 23:59 I would like to have the possibility to enter until 24.00 when I need to enter times like

18:00 - 24:00 equal 6:00 hours

Is there a solution? Thank you

```
    @objc func ActionDatePickerOraOrario(datePicker: UIDatePicker){
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = “HH:mm”
        switch datePicker.tag {
        case 1:
            TXTInizio.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        case 2:
            TXTFine.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        default:
            break
        }
    }

-----
let verOraInzio = Date().daStringAdate(format: "HH:mm", data: TXTInizio.text!)

let verOraFine = Date().daStringAdate(format: loc("formatoOra"), data: TXTFine.text!)

 let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: recInizio!, to: recFine!)

 let formattedStringDifferenza = String(format: "%02ld:%02ld", difference.hour!, difference.minute!)
```

Comment: 24:00 is not a valid time, after 23:59 comes 00:00.